# Disable deploy of jnilib

Tags: java, maven, java-native-interface

My users have been calling out for easily distributed native binaries with my library. I've got this working by distributing the natives in jars, which are [extracted at runtime into a temporary directory](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/blob/master/native_ref/java/src/main/java/com/github/fommil/jni/JniLoader.java).

However, the `maven-native-plugin` requires that the native is packaged as a `jnilib` (OS X), `so` (Linux) or `dll` (Windows). I have [my own deploy target](https://github.com/fommil/netlib-java/blob/master/native_ref/osx_64/pom.xml) that packages a `jar` file and distributes that under the classifier `natives`. It's a bit annoying that this needs a special classifier.

1. **How can I disable the deploy of the `jnilib/so/dll`**?
2. **How can I distribute my `jar` without any special classifier?**

Comment: JNLP solves this problem completely.

Comment: @EJP you'll have to explain why web start is even relevant in this context.

Comment: It is relevant because it is an application distribution mechanism that solves the JNI library problem you asked about.

Comment: That's not relevant at all. I'm building/bundling a middleware library and I specifically want to edit the deploy targets.

Answer (score 1):

I do a similar thing, but I pack the native libraries inside zip files. After that, in the artifact that needs them, I [pull and unpack](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-mojo.html) the zip file with the [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/):

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>    
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unzip</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>foo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.0</version>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                        <includes>**/*.dll</includes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/natives</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>    
</plugin>
```

As you can see I don't use any classifiers.

Comment: so downstream would then depend on the `<type>zip</type>`. Interesting. However, how do you disable the deploy of the maven native `jnilib`?

Comment: I do not use the maven native plugin at all, I create my own build process as I explain [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652649/native-maven-plugin-error-with-msvc-compiler-the-command-line-is-too-long/17686109#17686109), on the other side, I only create a dll for windows, and I haven't faced yet the problem of creating a multi-platform native library.

Comment: Yeah, you'd have problems as its effectively reinventing the wheel. Zip wouldn't work for me as my users want a dynamic file system independent load, which requires the natives to be on the class path (I.e. in a jar).